# How do I create a standalone signup/ login page in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, user-accounts

Im new to Meteor/iron-router and am following the Microscope project/ file structure.

My question is :
I dont want the usual drop down login box with {{> loginButtons}}. How do I set up a stand alone authentication page as the primary loaded page if user is not registered or logged in? It will have the usual email/pw and social logins.

This is the basic router code for easy reference. 
Do I just tweak the requireLogin part?

I also tried to use accounts-entry package but its fairly tough to figure how to use it.

Comment: Also check out the accounts entry package on Atmosphere

Answer (score 2):

You could also use an existing package from Atmosphere that provides a full-page login, such as [UserAccounts](http://useraccounts.meteor.com).

Comment: In the case above, the main page is home with "/". So I do need a new route like "/login"? Also Do i have to remove the existing accounts-ui package to use UserAccounts?

Comment: UserAccounts and accounts-ui should function independently of each other. You should be able to have one or both. With UserAccounts, you just need to put `{{> atForm}}` wherever you want your login form.

Comment: Also, UserAccounts allows you to easily add login routes, and provides an equivalent to your `requireLogin` function that redirects to the login page.

Comment: Just wondering, for the route above. I already have `"/"` as my homepage. How do I get UserAccounts to first route to the signup/login page using `{{> atForm}}` within that html? Doesnt seem to appear for mine though...maybe my routing is bad.

Comment: I think `{{> atForm}}` should just be replaced with the login form, wherever it is. Are you sure that you have added UserAccounts to your app?

Comment: Theres 3 issues now. 1) formatting is not as advertised, 2) How do I remove the header on sign in page (its embedded in header.html, which is positioned in layout.html) and 3) How do I shut off access to main home page? its still accessible if I click the home button in the header.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to just roll your own implementation with the [`Meteor.loginWithPassword`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword) and [`Meteor.loginWith<ExternalService>`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice) functions. You can call these functions when the relevant buttons on your login page are clicked.